# Variable doesn't exist in one locale

Tags: localization

I have a super strange problem.

I've created three locales: `de` `fr` `en`

I've set up all the necessary steps for a multi language config and everything works fine.

Except in the `en` locale I get a `Variable "xyz" does not exist`.

`de` and `fr` work just fine but english does not.

The variable is a `global field`. If I strip my templates from all `globals` it's working fine.

Otherwise each and every global field throws the `Variable does not exist` error in the `en` locale. How is that even possible when the other locales work just fine?

I' cant access the `en` `globals` in the control panel. Error: url not found. I guess this is a routing problem.

Answer (score 2):

If found the issue.

I didn't specify `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'de');` in the root `index.php`.

It doesnt suffice to create `en` `fr` folders and specify `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'xx');` there.

Comment: I'll leave it as an answer because this is so easy to miss.